# Is Qt capable of small-buffer low-latency video applications (e.g. live streaming)?

Tags: c++, qt, video, qmediaplayer

I am trying to create my own URL based live streaming application. I have hit an issue that the video streaming if having a delay of about 1000ms and there is no change in latency even after using LowLatency command. I want to achieve about 100ms latency video streaming.

( I want to genuinely know if Qt is the right tool for the job here, from people who know Qt and understand non-blocking, high priority, low latency programming. I already love Qt for its QML + JavaScript GUI building side.)

Comment: Did you achieve your 100ms goal? I'm trying to implement something similar and can't get less than 250ms video delay. about 100ms delay caused by PySide/pyqt

Answer (score 0):

> I want to genuinely know if Qt is the right tool for the job here

Yes.

(Of course it's up to you to use Qt to actually implement that).